# Celery is sending 600K requests in less than two weeks

Tags: celery, django-celery, amazon-sqs, celery-task

I received the monthly bill today for Amazon SQS and I was surprised to see 600.000 requests usage to my queue.

All I am doing is running one single task every minute.  How does this add up to 600.000 requests?

```
@celery.task(name='tasks.check_for_events')
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=1))  
def check_for_events():    
    now = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc,second=00, microsecond=00)
    events = Event.objects.filter(is_reminder_sent = False).filter(reminder_date_time__range=(now - timedelta(minutes=1), now))    
    dthandler = lambda obj: obj.isoformat() if isinstance(obj, datetime) else None    
    for event in events:
          sendEmail.delay( ...)


@celery.task(name='tasks.sendEmail')
def sendEmail(...)
    ....
```

I am still new to celery so it might be that I am doing something fundamentally wrong. 
Any tips please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, SQS considers sends, receives and deletes as requests.  So that's

```
>>> 600000 / 3
200000
```

tasks.

Last month there were 31 days.  So with the check for events task alone there were

```
>>> 60 * 24 * 31
44640
```

tasks or

```
>>> 44640 * 3
133920
```

requests used upfront.

Now, you'd only have to average

```
>>> (200000.0 - 44640) / 44640
3.4802867383512543
```

events per check_for_events invocation to get to 600k requests.

Now I'm not certain what volume of events you're dealing with, but perhaps this puts the usage more into perspective.

Comment: +1 from me. Thanks for the fantastic breakdown. Since I am very new to messaging, I wasn't aware that 3 messages are sent per task.  Hence since 3 actions (delete, sent, receive) are done per task, which runs per minute -> your approximate 3.48 per event seems correct. And I haven't set up anything wrong.  Thank you. that was very kind